# Anchor Links Open Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created an accordion with anchor links, my issue is how can I trigger the javascript to open the active accordion panel when the anchor link is selected.

```
    <script>

    $(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == 
    this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) 
    +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
    });
    });
    </script>

    <div class="Test">
        <a href="#Link 1st">A</a>
    </div>

   <button class="accordion"><strong><a id="Link 1st"></a>Link 1st</strong> 
   </button>

   <div class="panel"><br />
     <H4>Link 1</H4>
   </div>
```

Comment: you are closing the anchor tag before the text inside hence making the text not clickable.

Comment: I applied the revision, however the panel is still not opening when selected.